# Is it possible to integrate third party services into Nagios (respectively NEMS)? Using the Email Notifications via API would be enough

Tags: nagios, arp

I would like to integrate ARP Monitoring in Nagios respectively in NEMS (I need the last active IPs in the Network).
I would also like to integrate a already running script in Nagios which alarms me when the temperature of a sensor is higher then a given value. The notification should be send vias Nagios as an email.

Is it possible to send the notifications via Nagios for example with the API or is there any smarter way to do what I described?

Comment: Have you try to create new service check? This is standard practise

Comment: No I didn´t (I am new to Nagios and monitoring at all). So you mean I look up for a plug in and then I create a service check for this?

Comment: Correct. Even if you do not find any plugin you can write one on `bash`, `perl`, `python` or whatever language you are familiar with as far as you have interpreter/compiler for that language

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your personal contact details in contact groups and assign it to the particular host and service.